# Create room socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to create a simple node app where if a user press a button called 'create room', a room is created, the creator of the room joins it and make the room available for other players to join it with a limit of users. This is what I got so far (i'm beginner with sockets..)

///Server side

```
const app = require('express')();
const io = require('socket.io')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'))

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('create', room => socket.join(room) )
})

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => console.log('Server is up!'))
```

///Client side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>flip</title>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Create Room!</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

let socket = io.connect();


$('button').click(() => {
    socket.emit('create', 'room1')
})

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Semi-related (I didn't think to use socket.join and create a room like that), https://github.com/RUJodan/SourceUndead I used redis and sockets to make a faster-than-relational game lobby (room basically)

Comment: I'm using mysql as db..

Comment: That's ok, redis doesn't have to translate but the key here is you may be able to reference the socket methods to help you create a room

Comment: @Sterling Archer I'm just looking for a simple script to make me understand the sockets room concept, with redis might be better, but for now I'm a beginner :)